# Trying to Build DFA

Tags: automata, dfa

I'm trying to build Deterministic finite Automata this formal language

```
L = {w|w=Σ*0100} ⋂ {w=!Σ*11Σ*}
```

Any help building the automata

Comment: What does `sigma` denote here. I am finding little difficulty in understanding sigma. Can you please give some examples of numbers satisfying this language.

Comment: Σ* means that all the letters in alpha bet can be before the sequence 0100 my alpha bet is {0,1}.

Comment: Alright, working on it. Will post it in a while.

Comment: This is the language of words over `{0,1}` that do not contain `11` and end with `0100`. Can you use that definition to create an NFA for it, then convert the NFA into a DFA? That would likely be the easiest route. If you cannot find an NFA, maybe start with a regular expression and convert it to an NFA. The regular expression for this language is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your language accepts all the strings which end in `0100` but do not contain `11`. So, following automata satisfies your langauge.

[image]

**Explanation:**

- state `e` is the `null` state. If automata encounter two `1` consecutively, it goes to `null` state and then no matter what comes, it is stuck in non-terminating state.
- It search for `0100` and if it encounters it, it goes to terminating state `d`.

Comment: Happy to help. :) You can ask more questions if you need any help. You can tag me in the comment using @CodeTalker to Ask to answer, I enjoy solving automata questions.